# condition variable and #pragma pack bug

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, synchronization, g++

I found out that this piece of code doesn't work as intended:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

class myclass {
protected:
    bool mycrasher[1]; // with mycrasher[4] it works!
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;

    void thread_func() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        std::chrono::milliseconds timeout(1000);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx, std::defer_lock);
        while (true) {
            auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            l.lock();
            while (true) {
                std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;
                auto result = cv.wait_until(l, now + timeout);
                std::cout << "Timed out..." << std::endl;
                if (result == std::cv_status::timeout)
                    break;
            }
            l.unlock();
        }
    }   

public:
    myclass() { 
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mtx);
        std::thread *t = new std::thread(&myclass::thread_func, this);
        t->detach();
    };

    void start() {
        std::cout << "myclass started." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "sizeof(std::mutex) = " << sizeof(std::mutex) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "sizeof(std::condition_variable) = " << sizeof(std::condition_variable) << std::endl;
    }
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main() {
    myclass x;
    x.start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
}
```

I expected the code to wait for one second on the `cv.wait_until` call and then repeat, but is simply hangs on the call. The issue (intuitively) goes away if I remove the `#pragma` directives, because I'm packing the mutex and the CV. However, when I run this code I get:

```
myclass started.
sizeof(std::mutex) = 40
sizeof(std::condition_variable) = 48
```

with or without the `pragma`, so it seems the packing is not the real problem.

In addition, I discovered that if I align the `mycrasher` variable to a 4-bytes boundary the problem disappears as well. Likewise, if I move the variable after the `std::condition_variable cv` declaration the problem disappears, but when moved between `std::mutex mtx` and `std::condition_variable cv` it still persists.

Why the snippet hangs on the `cv.wait_until` call when the CV is not properly aligned? A performance hit would be expected, but not a plain stall.

Reproduced with g++ 4.9.2 and g++ 6.3 on a Debian 8 system.

Comment: The `#pragma pack` is only for *your* structure, not others that you use in your structure. It simply seems that you can't have mutexes or condition variables on odd addresses. Perhaps you can tell us *why* you want to use `#pragma pack`, what problem you try to solve with it, and we can help you with that problem instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, I just discovered that. I wanted to understand *why* it stops working. This should be part of a memory-intensive application, so having packed data aims to squeeze every byte.

Comment: @xmas79: That may backfire. Squeezing every byte can put unrelated data on the same cache line. This looks like another case of premature optimization.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks, I'm aware of the false sharing stuff. And I'm not saying I will keep the `#pragma pack` stuff here. I just had this code in my hands and wanted to know why it goes to hell, because I see no constraints in the docs about mtx and/or cv alignments.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use packing, you shouldn't do that with structures that have mutexes and condition variables. If you think that you really need that, then there is something wrong with your approach as you normally shouldn't create many of these objects and shouldn't need packing there.

As a simple workaround, place your `mycrasher` below your `mtx` and `cv`:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
class myclass
{
protected:
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool mycrasher[1];

    void thread_func();
public:
    myclass();
    void start();
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

The reason it's most likely doesn't work as expected with packing enabled is because `mtx` and `cv` end up on odd address and some internal code that uses these has different expectation. On some platforms (ARM for example) that might simply crash.

As a side note, your code not only has alignment issues, it also leaks a thread object on heap inside `myclass` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I already discovered. I can't find explicit expectation in mutex and/or cv documentation. So, why I **shouldn't do that with structures that have mutexes and condition variables**?

Comment: @xmas79 because it not normal to create many of them to require packing. These shouldn't be created in thousands or tens of thousands. You would need to step through the code with debugger to find out where data gets corrupted because of unexpected alignment. You may also try to build your program without optimizations, if problem still exists, then internally pthread functions expect that data properly aligned.

Comment: So it's not my fault and it's a library bug?

Comment: It's not clear why exactly the problem happens, if you try to use pthread directly with misaligned pthread structures and get the same outcome then internal pthread code is built with optimizations and this alignment assumption. I would never say that such pthread code has a bug, I'd definitely flag code that tries to squeeze synchronization primitives to some odd alignments.

Comment: currently on an Intel Core i7.